# Fiddler Autoresponder: Regex replacement not working

Tags: fiddler, auto-responder

I have a regex rule and an action that returns a file from a local cache. The rule captures what I want it to, but the problem is $2 in the action is not handled, so Fiddler tries to return D:\path\$2 (and fails). What could be wrong?

Rule:

```
regex:(?insx).*(host1.com|host2.com)/folder1/folder2/(.*)\?rev=.*
```

Action:

```
D:\path\$2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I'm using Fiddler v2.4.8.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After loosing an interesting amount of hair with this, I achieve it 'naming' the group replacement, like this:

Rule:

```
regex:(?insx).*(host1.com|host2.com)/folder1/folder2/(?'mygroup'.*)\?rev=.*
```

Action:

```
D:\path\${mygroup}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're using group replacements like this, it's important to put `^` at the front of the Rule expression and `$` at the end.